# SQL Server 2008 Time DataType Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, sqldatatypes

I am storing a check-in time and a check-out time in a table in SQL Server 2008.

When I store the time it shows correctly: `16:00:00` for example.

However when I pull this out of the database and bind it to the page to show the user the format displays as `16:00:00.0000000`

So the precision is obviously precise but I don't need that for this purpose.

I've tried `FormatDateTime` but that doesn't work (obviously) and cannot find anything for Classic ASP and SQL Server 2008 `Time` datatype on Google.

```
<%=(rsHotelFields.Item("checkintime").Value)%>
```

Any ideas on how to change the above?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: How you have tried to use `FormatDateTime`?

Comment: Yep. I did put that in the question above but you make a good point as I didn't clarify the issue with `FormatDateTime` - what type do you give it? I tried `<%=FormatDateTime(rsHotelFields.Item("checkintime").Value,2)%>` etc and none of them were recognised.

Comment: Can you change the datatype to `TIME(0)` ? This would store (and retrieve) the time without fractions of a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, if you define a column in SQL Server 2008 to be of datatype `TIME`, it will use the maximum possible accuracy - 7 digits for the fractional seconds, accurate down to 100ns.

This is fine - but if you don't need that kind of accuracy, you can define your column to be:

```
YourColumn TIME(0)
```

and then no fractional seconds will be stored, just `16:04:44` and this same value will also be retrieved again from the database table to be displayed.

Using `TIME(0)` also reduces the storage size of the column from 5 bytes to 3 bytes.

Read more about the date and time datatypes [for SQL Server 2008 and newer on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: That's good advice and I will implement that in the database. I can then apply `<%=rsHotelFields(rsProp.Fields.Item("checkintime").Value,vbShortTime)%>` which works perfectly to strip out the seconds column.  Many Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I meant: `<%=FormatDateTime(rsHotelFields.Fields.Item("checkintime").Value,vbShortTime)%>`